# Python iterates row data into another file

Tags: python-3.3

a python beginner here.

I come up with a small task so I could continue to learn and improve my python. I have an example file1:

```
Name:   Group:   UID:
user1   group1     12

user2   group2     23
user3   group3     34
user9   group9     99
```

I am trying to achieve the result in file2 column:

```
User_Name:   User_ID:     
user1          12
user9          99
```

I have gotten this far, and near the end is where I am stuck:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

with open("file1") as rfile:
   with open("file2", "w") as wfile:
     for line in rfile:
      l=line.strip()
       if l:
         x=l.split()
         #From here, I am not sure what to do next.
         if "user1" in x:
             do something...    
         if "user9" in x:
             do something..
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
wfile.write( x[0] + "\t" + x[2] + "\n")
```